# How to log fixture/test name before each fixture/test in testcafe

Tags: javascript, testcafe

I'm working on a project with lots of testcafe tests and I want to implement logging of the name of each fixture and test before the test runs. I know that I can use the `.before()` functions of a fixture, but that means I have to change each and every test we have. I also know that I can register global hooks, but the `ctx` property does not seem to hold any information.

Is there a way I can globally enable logging of each fixture/test name without changing each test?

As an example, I had hoped I would be able to do something like this:

**.testcaferc.js**

```js
module.exports = {
    hooks: {
      fixture: {
        before: async (ctx) => {
          console.log(`Executing fixture: ${ctx.fixtureName}`)  // ctx is empty :(
        }
      },
      test: {
        before: async (ctx) => {
          console.log(`Running test: ${ctx.testName}`)
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem, TestCafe provides the [Reporter Plugin](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402810/guides/extend-testcafe/reporter-plugin). It is used to format the results. You can also take any [existing reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=testcafe-reporter) and create a fork with the necessary logic.

Comment: Hmm okay thanks! That is a bit more work that I'd like but good that it's an option :)